# apache airflow : convert xml file to json file

Tags: xml, machine-learning, airflow

i'm actually extracting hotel data from sunhotels, the data is in xml format, so i would like to use apache airflow and build a DAG to convert xml file to json.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PythonOperator and use the library xmltodict to create a function callable in the Operator. Example code as belows

```
import json, xmltodict
with open("xml_file.xml") as xml_file:
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
    xml_file.close()
json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
with open("data.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_data)
        json_file.close()
```

Comment: thank you so much Mohanty, let me try that